# How to change header & footer to full width?

Tags: wordpress, header, footer

I'm using the Sleketon theme on this website.

What I'd like to do is have the header & footer to "fill" all horizontal space of the screen, while having the main content staying as is.

Actually, what I'd like is the background color to fill full width of screen(dark blue and red lines for header, dark blue, red and green lines for footer). I'd like the content to stay where it is.

I've looked at several other threads, but I couldn't manage to make my way to the solution with the Skeleton theme.

Can you guys please help me out ?

Thanks

EDIT : I just realized I didn't add the [website url](http://www.tophostingtoday.com).

Answer (score 3):

If you have your CSS file linked you can target it by class .header / .footer and add the line : width:auto;
I suggest adding a container/wrapper div and place all your contents in it.

Should look something like this:

```
    html, body { margin:0px; padding:0px; }

    .wrapper { margin:auto; width:auto; }

    .header { margin:auto; height:200px; width:auto; background-color:#0000FF; border:1px solid #DF0101; }

    .content{ margin:auto; height:500px; width:800px; }

    .footer { margin:auto; height:100px; width:auto; background-color:#0000FF; border:1px solid #DF0101; border-top:1px solid #3ADF00; border-bottom:1px solid #3ADF00; }
```

Hope this helps.

~ Jeff

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but I'm not sure I understand. I'm using a custom css plugin that overrides the original theme css : I should paste the above code in this custom css, right ? Plus, how do I place all the content in a container/wrapper div ? (sorry for the dumb question)

Comment: You can paste the codes above in the original theme and you should!
Its good to use one css file.

If you open up the code for the website .html or .php file
you can add a div.

        <div class="wrapper"></div>

everything you place between <div> and </div> will be within the wrapper div.

Comment: When and if you add the wrapper which is not necessary it just gives you more control. You can add a padding in the css file under .wrapper if you say padding:20px; it will move all data within the wrapper div 20pixels away from the top / sides and bottom.